# Getting error as java.lang.NullPointerException while iterating webelement from Set<WebElement> using FindAll and PageObject

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, collections, pageobjects, findall

I was trying to automate to select drop down option with set<WebElement> , but while iterating it gives error as NullPointerException . I same tried with List<WebElement> , It works fine.

```
UserPageObject.java
----------------------------

 @FindAll({@FindBy(xpath ="//li[@role='option']/span[@class='ng-star-inserted']")})
    private Set<WebElement> DropDownElementStatus;

 public Set<WebElement> getDropDownElementStatus() {
        return DropDownElementStatus;
    }

    public void setDropDownElementStatus(Set<WebElement> dropDownElementStatus) {
        DropDownElementStatus = dropDownElementStatus;
    }


 ActionsUtilities.java 
---------------------------

public void AllDropDownSetElements(Set<WebElement> dropDownsElements, String DropDownOption ){
        Iterator<WebElement>  dropDownIteratorElements= dropDownsElements.iterator(); //getting error as NullPointerException on this line
        while(dropDownIteratorElements.hasNext())
        {
            WebElement element= dropDownIteratorElements.next();
            if(element.getText().trim().equals(DropDownOption))
                element.click();
        }
    }   



UserStepDefifnation.java
-----------------------------

objectList.getActionsUtilities().AllDropDownSetElements(objectList.getUserPageObject().getDropDownElementStatus(),"INACTIVE");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like [`findElements()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElements(org.openqa.selenium.By)) returns a *List* of [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139)s:

```
java.util.List<WebElement> findElements​(By by)
```

Annotation Type [`FindAll()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/FindAll.html) is used to mark a field on a Page Object to indicate that lookup should use a series of `@FindBy` tags. It will then search for all elements that match any of the *FindBy* criteria. However, elements are not guaranteed to be in document order.

```
@FindAll({@FindBy(xpath ="//li[@role='option']/span[@class='ng-star-inserted']")})
    private List<WebElement> DropDownElementStatus;
```

It can be used on a types as well as follows:

```
@FindAll({@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "foo"),
          @FindBy(className = "bar")})
```

To conclude, `@FindAll` would return a *List* but not a *Set*, which you have to incorporate within yours tests.